# Translate ruby to python

Tags: python, ruby, algorithm, translation

I'm rewriting some code from Ruby to Python. The code is for a [Perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), listed in section 8.2.6 of [Clever Algorithms: Nature-Inspired Programming Recipes](http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/). I've never used Ruby before and I don't understand this part:

```
def test_weights(weights, domain, num_inputs)
  correct = 0
  domain.each do |pattern|
    input_vector = Array.new(num_inputs) {|k| pattern[k].to_f}
    output = get_output(weights, input_vector)
    correct += 1 if output.round == pattern.last
  end
  return correct
end
```

Some explanation: `num_inputs` is an integer (2 in my case), and `domain` is a list of arrays: `[[1,0,1], [0,0,0], etc.]`

I don't understand this line:

```
input_vector = Array.new(num_inputs) {|k| pattern[k].to_f}
```

It creates an array with 2 values, every values `|k|` stores `pattern[k].to_f`, but what is `pattern[k].to_f`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
input_vector = [float(pattern[i]) for i in range(num_inputs)]
```

Comment: float() isn't necessary in python, I think it's a ruby thing that I can't understand now...

Comment: @paolocappelletto, it depends on what `get_output` does. Integer division in Python 2 can give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern[k].to_f
```

converts `pattern[k]` to a float.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Ruby expert, but I think it would be something like this in Python:

```
def test_weights(weights, domain, num_inputs):
    correct = 0
    for pattern in domain:
        output = get_output(weights, pattern[:num_inputs])
        if round(output) == pattern[-1]:
            correct += 1
    return correct
```

There is plenty of scope for optimising this: if `num_inputs` is always one less then the length of the lists in `domain` then you may not need that parameter at all.

Be careful about doing line by line translations from one language to another: that tends not to give good results no matter what languages are involved.

**Edit:** since you said you don't think you need to convert to float you can just slice the required number of elements from the domain value. I've updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm totally agree with you about line by line translation, my problem is that I'm missing the behavior below the code. with Array.new(2) I create an array with two values, every value is equal the current value of domain list (I don't think is necessary to convert to float)... oh god I need a coffe...